# Java Hosting APR based Apache Tomcat Error

Tags: java, tomcat, hosting, apr, metaspace

I think this is a 2 part question.
My versions:
I developed using Java jdk1.8.0_144,
Server JVM jdk1.8.0_77,
Server Tomcat apache-tomcat-8.5.23

**Error:
16-Apr-2018 11:57:31.041 SEVERE [http-nio-13571-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init An incompatible version [1.1.32] of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version [1.2.14]**

I tried different Java version, including Java 9 and Java 7. On these version my app does not even start up. I tried 2 different Java 8 versions supplied by the hosting company and still get the same error.

Any ideas please?

Then I got the error above and did nothing else on the website. Did not even browse it. Hours later I get this error:

**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace**

The hosting company says I musttake a better hosting option for more Memory and then the errors will  go away?
What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is conflicting your tomcat version, it may be older version.
Download the native library of required version and replace this file tcnative-1.dll(locate at your tomcat bin folder) with new downloaded file.

Download from this link https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/native/.

It will work.